# How to perform password reset in Node.Js app using hash?

Tags: node.js, hash, change-password

I want to implement password reset in my Node.Js app using a very good advice from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27580553/712347 where I would not have to record any tokens into my database.

Instead @airtonix suggested to use a hash function based on the user's login, email, password, timestamp, secret and salt.

What I don't understand is how do hash functions actually work — let's say I get a certain sequence from the data above — what would be the algorithm (and the library) to use to check if it was generated from the same data using a different salt?

Or am I misunderstanding the whole thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How do Hash functions generally actually work -**

Hash Algorithms create a digital fingerprint of data usually called Digest or Hash. You primarily see Hash Algorithms used for comparison purposes rather than encryption.

Secure Hash Algorithms have some fundamental characteristics such as:

- Non-reversible (*one way function*). You cannot determine the original set of data from the Digest.
- The Digest will be a fixed size regardless of the original data's size.
- Unique. Two different data sets cannot produce the same Digest.

**What would be the algorithm and the library to use?**

I would recommend SHA-2 (SHA-256 or SHA-512) as the hashing algorithm and utilize the [Crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). It provides cryptographic functionality and a set of wrappers for OpenSSL's hash, HMAC, cipher, decipher, sign, and verify functions.

So lets say we have the following information (*user.id, user.email, user.password, timestamp*), concatenate it and pass it as the data parameter.

```
const hash = function hash(data){

   // Returns a buffer containing raw bytes and converts to string
   const salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64')

   // Creates and returns a Hmac object that uses the given algorithm
   const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', salt)

   // Updates the Hmac object content with the given data
   hmac.update(data)

   // Calculates the digest of all of the data passed to be hashed
   const digest = hmac.digest('hex')

   return {
     'salt'  : salt,
     'digest': digest
   } 

}
```

Running the above function with the same data but a different salt would result in a completely different Digest.